# Replace colors in an image using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to replace specific rgb values with new ones quickly using numpy. So far this is what I have:

```
    def magic(self, tmp_img, color_combination_image, hsv, old_rgb):
        for color_to_swap_with in old_rgb:
            for new_color in color_combination_image:
                red, blue, green = tmp_img[:,:,:0], tmp_img[:,:,:1], tmp_img[:,:,:2]
                mask = (red == color_to_swap_with[0]) & (green == color_to_swap_with[1]) & (blue == color_to_swap_with[2])
                tmp_img[:,:,:3][mask] = [new_color[0], new_color[1], new_color[2]]
            tmp_image_name= self.image_name + "-swappedcolors-" + str(random.random()) + ".jpg"
            tmp_path = self.path_to_swapped_colors+tmp_image_name.split(".")[0]+"/"+tmp_image_name
            cv2.imwrite(tmp_path, tmp_img)
```

But when I execute the code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1219:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "driver.py", line 326, in magic
    mask = (red == color_to_swap_with[0]) & (green == color_to_swap_with[1]) & (blue == color_to_swap_with[2])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5533,3774,0) (5533,3774,2)
```

What can I do to fix this? I'm operating on the same image, I don't know why the shapes are different.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your entire issue, but `red` is a `(5533, 3774, 0)` shape array because you used `tmp_img[:, :, :0]` which slices a length 0 array in the last dimension instead of `tmp_img[:, :, 0]` which accesses the 0th index in that dimension.

Comment: what is old_rgb?